# Google Analytics regular expression for matching page URIs at specified path levels

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I am trying to build a regular expression for a page-level report in Google Analytics to match pages that exist at a specified level in the path/directory, and exclude pages in the report beyond that level.

More specifically, to only show page URIs in the report that are at the 5th path level, or rather, URIs that contain 5 "/"s only, and no more.

(The seperate drill-down content report in Analytics only offers separation to 4 levels in the path, which is therefore not suitable in this case.)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit:

Using an example below, I am currently able to build a regular expression that matches the following Page URIs:

```
/about/team/member1/bio/info
/about/team/member2/bio/address
/about/team/member2/bio/address?=2335
/about/team/member3/bio/contact
/about/team/member3/bio/contact/method
/about/team/member4/bio/p321
/about/team/member4/bio/p321/test
```

However I would like the regular expression to exclude the pages above in rows 3,5 and 7 or any other page URIs for that matter that exceed 5 levels in the path.  Also, just to add, that the 5th level in the path could contain any letters and/or numbers.

Comment: You should provide an example of the url format; guessing at regex pattern mattern doesn't often work.

Comment: @l'L'l - thanks for the reply.  Please see the URI format in original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which regex flavor GA uses, but this is fairly standard and matches all the rows except 3,5 and 7.

```
^(?:/[a-zA-Z0-9]+){1,5}$
```

In case GA doesn't support non-capturing groups, go with this:

```
^(/[a-zA-Z0-9]+){1,5}$
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Would it be possible to explain non-capturing groups, and this: {1,5} - presumably this is the occurrences?

Could I work it this in to the current regular expression that I already have (?):

    ^\/about\/team\/member[1-4]\/bio\/

Comment: I think I may have just achived this: ^\/about\/team\/member[1-4]\/bio\/(([a-zA-Z0-9]+){1})$

Comment: @user3526779 {1,5} means "match the expression in the preceding parentheses between 1 and 5 times. Capturing parenthesis allow you to reuse the match inside the parentheses by referring to their content later in the expression with the help of \1 of $1. Here we don't need capturing parentheses. Let me know if you need any tweaks. I see this may be your first question: when someone has what you feel is the right answer, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that Analytics' guide on regex only scratches the surface on this.  It occurred to me that some of the pages URIs may contain an underscore in the 5th level of the path.  With this in mind, would this regex be correct, or am I being a newbie?:      ^\/about\/team\/member[1-4]\/bio\/(([a-zA-Z0-9_]+){1})$

Comment: @user3526779 Your insight to throw the underscore into the character class is correct. In this particular case, you can replace the whole character class with \w+ as \w happens to match letters numbers and underscores. You never need a {1}, as by default the engine matches what you specify once. Your [1-4] means that you are matching from member1 up to member4.