# Regex to match 2 level deep URL and not 3 level deep (Google Analytics)

Tags: regex

I'm trying to create content groups in Google Analytics.  How do I match a page with sport/[SOMETHING] and not sport/[SOMETHING]/[SOMETHING]

Match:

- /sport/football
- /sport/mens-basketball
- /sport/baseball

Do not Match:

- /sport/mens-basketball/standings
- /sport/football/standings
- /sport/football/scores

Comment: looks like `[^/]` will solve your problems (not /), so you can consume any amount of "not /" and then the / and so on to restrict the number of levels. e.g. `^/sport/[^/]+$`

Comment: Can you please provide an example @maraca?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Analytics regular expression for matching page URIs at specified path levels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23031093/google-analytics-regular-expression-for-matching-page-uris-at-specified-path-lev)

Comment: @melpomene indeed a duplicate, but the given answer is not correct, fails for _, - (which Hung Luu has)  and other characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can say "not the following characters" using `[^...]` the `^` stands for "not". So to restrict the levels we can use `[^/]`.

Here some examples:

Match /sport/something : `^/sport/[^/]+$`

Has to start with / and then exactly 1 / has to follow: `^/[^/]+/[^/]+$` or `^(/[^/]+){2}$`

Generalized for start with / and followed by 4 / at most: `^(/[^/]+){1,5}$`

Comment: This works in Google Analytics but using a RegEx tester like http://www.regexr.com/, it doesn't work.  Not sure why

Comment: You have to escape the / there --> `\/` ( / is sometimes used to define a regex)

Comment: ^\/sports\/([^\/]+)\/$ this should work as mentioned by Luis Montoya

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me         `^\/sports\/([^\/]+)\/$`

Explanation:
^/sports/ => category to match with / escaped using \

([^/]+) => the not / once or more

/$ => the closing first level page depth / with a $ stop