# Matching Multiple Level Deep URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been trying to write a regex on javascript that helps matches URL exactly 2 level deep URL in the following format:

```
https://myurl.com/x/y/z
https://anotherurl.com/ab9/zx/qs
```

I have tried couple of revelant regex suggested in other answers and tried modifying them for my own purposes - however to no avail: [Regex to match 2 level deep URL and not 3 level deep (Google Analytics)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688762/regex-to-match-2-level-deep-url-and-not-3-level-deep-google-analytics), https://mixedanalytics.com/blog/regex-match-number-subdirectories-url/

Could someone shade some light? Please pardon my lack of knowledge in regex. I am just starting out.

Comment: What do you mean by __2 level deep__ do you want to match `Url`s with two subdirectories?

Comment: Should the examples match or not? The examples have 3 levels, right?

Comment: You might do that using a quantifier specifying how many times to repeat the 'match forward slash, not forward slash` pattern `^https?:\/\/[^/]+(?:\/[^/]+){3}$` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/bvlkTK/1/) Note that matching not a forward slash also matches line break characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Regular Expression which I think you want something like this:-

```
\^(?:https|http)\:\/\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+$\
```

#### The Explanation:-

- `^` : The first of the string.
- `(?: ... )` : A non-capturing group.
- `https|http` : Matches both `https` and `http`.
- `\:\/\/` : Matches `://` which appear after `https`.
- `[^\/]+` : Matches anything except `/`, and the plus means one or more occurrences(letters or symbols).
- `\/` : Matches `/` symbol.
- `$` : The end of the string.

And the other part of the regex code is repeated and described above, and also if you don't understand the explanation open [this](https://regex101.com/r/lWtqsq/1) link this describes more nicely than me, but I didn't wrote **2 level deep URL** because your examples aren't two level deep URL, they're 3 level deep URL, And if you just want 2 level deep URL without looking at your examples so use this instead:-

```
\^(?:https|http)\:\/\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+\/[^\/]+$\
```